# Beginning Python printing out standard deviation

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. Could anyone fix it?

```
def main():
   fname = input("Enter filename:")
   infile = open(fname, "r")
   SD()

def SD():
  b= []
  a = 5.0 
  r = len(b) 
  for n in range(r-1):
      b.append((r[n] -a)**2)
  m = (float(b)/r)**0.5
  print("The standard deviation is", m)
main()
```

Comment: what makes you think there's a problem? (what output are you getting, and what do you expect to get?)

Comment: I got this error message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python32\new.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Python32\new.py", line 4, in main
    SD()
  File "C:\Python32\new.py", line 12, in SD
    m = (float(b)/r)**0.5
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number

Comment: @LorraineJane: `b` is a list not a number to be divided by r, secondly, len(b) will be `0` as `b = []`, please check if this is what you intend to do.

Comment: Alternately, assuming you're not just writing a `stddev()` function as an exercise - i.e. you actually want to calculate standard deviations of data for a project - you could use [`numpy.std()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a handful of errors:

```
def SD():

  # b is empty
  b= []
  a = 5.0 

  #this will always be 0
  r = len(b) 

  # range(r-1) == [] because it is range(-1)
  # whole loop is skipped
  for n in range(r-1):
      b.append((r[n] -a)**2)

  # float(b) should throw an error, maybe sum(b) ?
  m = (float(b)/r)**0.5
  print("The standard deviation is", m)
main()
```

`b` is a list; you can't cast a list into a float.

perhaps you want to pass an array to `SD()`? You should `read()` the files contents and then perhaps `split()` that into an array and pass it to SD() as an argument (where you'll call `int()` on them.)

Answer (score 1):

For a sample:

```
def SD(numList):
    cntN=len(numList)
    sumN=0
    for i in numList:
        sumN+=i
    avgVal=float(sumN)/float(cntN)
    sumVar=0.0
    for i in range(cntN):
        sumVar+=float((numList[i]-avgVal)**2)
    return ((float(sumVar)/float((cntN-1)))**0.5)
```